# ¿Como puedo instalar Mac snow leopard en virtual box?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtualización

Quiero instalar Mac Snow Leopard en una maquina virtual, pero no puedo hacer el proceso de instalación, he leído que necesito usar iBoot, ya lo descargue pero me arroja un error que es: bios disk read error at sector: 00000011, y ahorita baje otra iso de Snow Leopard pero se queda trabajando, alguien puede decirme como puedo instalar Mac Snow leopard? o algun programa que trabaje en windows para desarrollar aplicaciones para iOS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para virtualizar mac en windows con virtualbox, los discos originales de mac no funcionan ya que necesitan modificaciones al SO para trabajar bien la maquina virtual. 
En internet hay [ejemplos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2eftyJZ8Lg) que generalmente usan imágenes del SO ya modificadas y preparadas para funcionar como maquina virtual. Prueba con otras versiones de Mac porque no siempre se puede con la versión que deseas (Snow leopard).

Si quieres programar objective C en windows esta [GNUStep](http://wwwmain.gnustep.org/resources/downloads.php?site=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.gnustep.org%2Fpub%2Fgnustep%2F). Debes bajar msys-system, core, devel, cairo, ProjectCenter y Gorm he instalarlos en ese orden. Aunque he progamado Objective C aqui, todo lo que he hecho es modo consola ya que la interfaz gráfica deja mucho que desear porque se parece al viejo Xcode con Interface Buider y desconozco si soporte iOS.